# MySQL database: high performance random lookups

Tags: php, mysql, performance, scalability

I'm designing the backend of a high performance scalable database which has the need to select random rows within certain categories very quickly. To give a general picture of this, there is one huge table of rows each with a 'category' field, and then perhaps 10 million rows in it with anything up to 500 different categories existing.

My first thought to improve performance on picking these was to create a separate lookup table, indexed just by category so that the pseudocode would be something like:

- Generate random number between 0 and the count of rows with category 'example' in lookup_table
- Select row from lookup_table WHERE category='example' LIMIT random_number,1

This would use the index to generate a row count of matching rows and then select a random one and pluck it out. It turns out that after about 20,000 rows per category this was taking upwards of 0.02 seconds to pick out rows, which wasn't ideal with many similar operations concurrently.

My second thought and what I may run with now is a separate database or group of lookup tables, as the database is ripe for sharding once we scale, with a table per category. Random lookups will then be near instantaneous as they can be performed on the primary key at a random number from the table count.

I'd much appreciate if any wizards here with similar experiences have any thoughts to share on this, or if there's a feature I'm missing which would help. I looked into partitioning the table into 500 odd categories but it didn't seem like it would be of much use for this scenario.

Thanks!

**Edit** Another consideration which has largely affected design is that each item may have multiple categories, and needs to be able to be randomly selected by any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using LIMIT, add a new column `rnd` to the lookup table with type float. Create an index on (category, rnd) and initialize it with `UPDATE table SET rnd = RAND()`. Then use:

```
SET $rndValue = RAND();
SELECT id FROM lookup_table WHERE category = 'example' AND rnd < @rndValue ORDER BY `rnd` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

to find a random row efficiently. You might want to put this in a loop since if @rndValue ends up being 0 it will not find any row (or if there are no objects in that category).